# ICEfaces CollapsiblePanel with link in header

Tags: jsf, components, icefaces

I'm trying to put a commandLink in the header of an ICEfaces collapsible panel. But whenever I click the link the panel gets collapsed as well (which is not what I wanted).

Some guy in a forum found a solution but honestly I don't understand it as I'm quite new to JSF and ICEfaces.
http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/posts/list/8931.page

Can anybody give a more detailed explanation what to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Must be the "toggleOnClick" = false attribute on the collpasiblePanelHeader tag.